# Cannot create a VSTS webhook subscription via the REST API

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to register a webhook subscription to notify my application when a work item is edited. I thought I would start by adding a `workitem.created` webhook. However — I am getting the same error response, whatever subscription I try to register, including the example from the documentation. Here is my example:

**POST:**

```
https://{my-app}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/?api-version=1.0
```

**Headers:**

```
Authorization:Bearer my-auth-token
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "build.complete",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0-preview.1",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "publisherInputs": {
    "buildStatus": "Failed",
    "definitionName": "MyWebSite CI",
    "projectId": "my-project-id"
  },
  "consumerInputs": {
    "url": "https://requestb.in/14xw4741"
  }
}
```

**The error response I get:**

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: ecb81b36-4a77-4ae8-9d13-1a5dbb473c8a.",
    "typeName": "System.Exception, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "Exception",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

**I have tried multiple API versions:**

```
api-version=4.1-preview
api-version=1.0
api-version=2.0
api-version=3.0
```

I have also tried multiple `resourceVersion`s.

I have the following auth token scope: `vso.dashboards`, `vso.identity`, `vso.notification_manage`, `vso.work_full`, `vso.workitemsearch`

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Bearer Token using the REST API, and a feedback already submitted to the VSTS team : [Create webhook with workitem.created EventType and OAuth token fail](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/149872/create-webhook-with-workitemcreated-eventtype-and.html)

As a workaround, you can use basic Authorization, **you can use personal access token or alternate account instead.** I tested with below PS sample and that worked for me.

e.g:

```
Param(
   [string]$vsoAccount = "YouVsoAccount",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "xxxx",
   [string]$token = "qwdiqwaey4aosdgbyqhrdpnvwitguqe2kqllcoc46vvvrxxxkiruq"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"

{"consumerActionId":"httpRequest","consumerId":"webHooks","consumerInputs":{"url":"http://xxxx"},"eventType":"workitem.updated","publisherId":"tfs","publisherInputs":{"areaPath":"\\TFVC\\","workItemType":"","changedFields":"","projectId":"0142146b-3ee9-495f-8ef0-e8fe223d6571"},"resourceVersion":"1.0","scope":1}

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "https://$($vsoAccount).visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=1.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

Write-Host $base64AuthInfo

Similar thread for your reference : [Creating VSTS ServiceHooks (WebHooks) via Rest Api for work item created event fails. Please give a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217833/creating-vsts-servicehooks-webhooks-via-rest-api-for-work-item-created-event-f)

---

**UPDATE:**

`Authorization: Basic base-64-token-here` works on my side. Please make sure you have the correct `Base64-encodes` there.

Actually you just need to paste the PAT as the password under `Authorization` tab in Postman, it will automatically encode the token in Postman.

Another way is encode the PAT in other tools (e.g. you can output the `$base64AuthInfo` from above PS sample ), then copy and paste the `base-64-token` in the header. Both works for me.

To output the $base64AuthInfo : `Write-Host $base64AuthInfo`

[image]

Comment: Cheers for the reply...

I just get a sign in page back...

Just to confirm, I am encoding my oAuth access token (PAT) to a Base64 string and adding the header:

`Authorization: Basic base-64-token-here` 

Can we try to keep the code language-agnostic? I'm not using C# — so let's just talk in terms of REST APIs :)

Full response here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/149872/create-webhook-with-workitemcreated-eventtype-and.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/149872/create-webhook-with-workitemcreated-eventtype-and.html)

Comment: @jpsear `Authorization: Basic base-64-token-here` works on my side. Please make sure you have the correct `Base64-encodes` there. Actually you just need to paste the PAT as the password under `Authorization` tab in Postman, it will automatically encode the token in Postman. Another way is encode the token in other tools (e.g. you can output the `$base64AuthInfo` from the PS sample ), then copy and paste the `base-64-token` in the header. Both works for me. Please see the udpated answer for details.

Comment: Okay — I think I am following you now, the PAT is actually different from a JWT. I was pasting my Base64 encoded JWT as the Basic auth token. I have managed to make it work using a PAT generated from the user's account. However — this is not ideal at all.

Can I at least programatically generate a PAT? I don't want the user to have to manage tokens etc...

Comment: @jpsear Your requirement is creating webhook subscription via the REST API, this can be achieved by the PS sample posted in above answer. Whatever action it needs the credential (token or password). So you need to create a user/password or token first. Once the PAT created for the user, then the token can be used directly. But why you want to create the PAT (personal access token) programatically? Maybe this article helps to understand that : https://www.domstamand.com/accessing-tfs-2017-programmatically/

Comment: @jpsear And what is the JWT? whatever please see this article to use the PAT : [Authenticate access with personal access tokens for VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate)

Comment: Just a follow up for anyone wondering — it _is_ possible to create a webhook without having to ask to user to provide you a PAT. There is currently a bug with the `vso.work_full` scope. Using the `vso.work_write` scope works. The issue is set to be resolved before Feb 2018...